# How can I avoid a circular dependency when building out of tree module and kernel with initramfs?

Tags: initramfs, module

I'm cross compiling a kernel and have an out of tree kernel modules provided by a device vendor.  Originally the kernel was built, then the module which worked fine.

Now I'm trying to enable initramfs in the kernel.  The kernel module needs to be included in the initramfs image.  This causes a circular dependency:

- The kernel depends on the initramfs image file (set in `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE`)
- The initramfs image file depends on the out of tree kernel module
- The out of tree kernel module depends on the kernel being built

The best workaround I have is:

1. create an empty file for the initramfs rootfs image
2. Build the kernel
3. Build the module
4. Build the real initramfs image
5. Re-build the kernel

However this breaks the `make` dependency tracking and causes a lot of un-necessary rebuilds during the normal development cycle.  Is there a kernel build target that will build the tools needed by an out of tree module without actually building the entire kernel?

Comment: Have you considered using a separate initramfs builder, like `dracut` for example? If your target architecture's bootloader requires the kernel and initramfs to both be in a single file, you could concatenate them together as the last step. The initramfs is just a sequence of one or more cpio archives. Each of them can optionally be compressed.

Comment: @telcoM I am using a separate initramfs builder (in my case buildroot) to create the initramfs CPIO image.  The kernel & initramfs do need to be a single image due to disk partition requirements.  Is the initramfs image literally concatenated to the end of the kernel image?  The kernel will know to find it there at boot?

Comment: The exact steps of loading the kernel will depend on the hardware architecture used, and you haven't mentioned it. Since you say you will be cross-compiling, and you mention partition requirements, I guess your target architecture is something other than a PC-style x86. Depending on the architecture and bootloader used, there might or might not be a data field that needs to be updated to describe the total size of stuff the bootloader copied to RAM.

Comment: I found `make modules_prepare` for the kernel which simplified the build order.  However it didn't solve all dependencies so I went with @telcoM solution and added the initramfs as a new image in the kernel's FIT (u-boot) object.